# Ubuntu 16.04 DNS lookup timeout with IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with dnsmasq 2.75 that I'm trying to setup for querying DNS using IPv6 servers, but I'm getting timeouts. I have a Windows box on the same network that is able to query DNS using the same IPv6 server with no issue.  I've checked firewall and I can see the request going out but the server just returns a timeout.

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
server=2001:4860:4860::8888
server=2001:4860:4860::8844
```

**nslookup**

```
administrator@server:~$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

administrator@server:~$ nslookup google.com 2001:4860:4860::8888
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**dig**

```
administrator@server-01:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

administrator@server-01:~$ dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**NOTE**: The ubuntu server has IPv6 connectivity, I'm able to get to an IPv6 IP out on the internet.

To show that I can get out to IPv6 server here are example:

**Ping**

```
administrator@server-01:~$ ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=31.4 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=33.5 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=34.7 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8888: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=32.9 ms
^C
--- 2001:4860:4860::8888 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.411/33.142/34.708/1.210 ms
```

**Http Request**

Destination:  ipv6.google.com (2607:f8b0:4000:804::200e)

```
administrator@server-01:~$ wget http://[2607:f8b0:4000:804::200e]/
--2017-10-24 08:26:03--  http://[2607:f8b0:4000:804::200e]/
Connecting to [2607:f8b0:4000:804::200e]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-24 08:26:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: 1) Can you demonstrate that it has connectivity? Can it ping IPv6 hosts; can it visit HTTP websites via IPv6; can it resolve names from _other_ (non-Google) DNS servers? 2) Can you traceroute to the Google DNS server? 3) Is your ISP called "Cogent"?

Comment: @grawity I updated my question to include ping and an http request, they both work.  I tried using opendns ipv6 and that fails also, which is not surprising.  There must be some setting with ubuntu/dnsmasq for ipv6 that I'm missing.  No I'm not using Cogent.

Comment: # dpkg --purge --force-all dnsmasq-base

Comment: @milli what does that do ?

Comment: Gets rid of dnsmasq